# Exporting Sharepoint 2013 wiki page to another sharepoint platform?

Tags: export, wiki

I was given a task to export a wiki page from one SharePoint site to another which is on different server. How could I achieve this? I don't know the details about a wiki page, I don't if it will have web parts or lists which would make this task a lot harder. Any ideas?